# Xorg laggy with AMD GPU

Tags: xorg, drivers, graphics, gnome-shell, amd-graphics

**THE PROBLEM**

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my desktop PC. For some odd reason, whenever I log into Gnome in Xorg mode, everything lags to the point where it's unusable. This doesn't happen when the GPU drivers don't load, for example after resuming boot after booting into recovery mode.

So far, I've been able to get around this by using Wayland instead, but I'd like to be able to use Xorg too.

**POTENTIONAL POINTS OF FAILURE**

I have a Ryzen 2200G (APU) and an RX 560 (GPU). I also use 2 monitors. Those are all the hardware oriented points of failure that I can think of.

**GOAL**

Fix Xorg lag and make sure that the dedicated GPU is being used for rendering.

**FURTHER INFORMATION**

This is the output of `inxi -Gxx`

```
Graphics:  Device-1: AMD Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X] 
           vendor: Sapphire Limited driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 10:00.0 chip ID: 1002:67ef 
           Device-2: AMD Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] driver: amdgpu 
           v: kernel bus ID: 38:00.0 chip ID: 1002:15dd 
           Display: wayland server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: ati,fbdev unloaded: modesetting,radeon,vesa 
           compositor: gnome-shell resolution: 1680x1050~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.33.0 5.3.0-23-generic LLVM 9.0.0) v: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.1 
           direct render: Yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've been able to find on AMD's website, they don't support Ubuntu 19.10. As a result, I downgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as there doesn't seem to be any other way to resolve my issues without any major workarounds.